# Pinch zoom canvas with dynamic image each time for cordova app

Tags: javascript, html, css, cordova, ionic-framework

Wanted to add pinch zoom feature in a ionic mobile app. So tried using the pinch-zoom-canvas javascript in npm. So my task was to show the canvas in a modal on clicking a image which can then be pinch zoomed. The problem is that it only works for the first time after that the modal is not showing the image in canvas. When inspected through chrome, the canvas's clientWidth and clientHeight is automatically setting to 0 after the first time. Tried to fix this by setting width and height through inline css and style.css, but not working.

This is the link to the pinch-zoom-canvas js in npm: https://www.npmjs.com/package/pinch-zoom-canvas

[The sample function code used in the project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7M5an.png)